# I want 1 nginx ingress resource for all my 10 services

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I have 10 services in node and in each service I have multiple get and post requests. They are running fine in GCP app engine with this app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: feedservice
instance_class: F4
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 7

runtime: nodejs14
service: walletservice
instance_class: F4
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 4
```

Now I have deployed them to aws eks. I have exposed them with Nginx ingress controller this is my ingress.yaml

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: my-ingress
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    spec:
      ingressClassName: nginx
      rules:
        - host: myapp.example.com
          http:
            paths:
              - path: /feedservice
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: feedservice
                    port:
                      number: 8081
              - path: /walletservice
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: walletservice
                    port:
                      number: 8081
.
.
and so on
```

The thing is appengine automatically put servicename in the base url and then I can get my get and post request like this:  https://myappengineurl/servicename/getrequest1 , https://myappengineurl/servicename/getrequest2 , https://myappengineurl/servicename2/getrequest1 and so on.

I have exposed my node services like this:

```
    app.get('/getrequest1', jsonParser, async (request, response) => {
    //my code
     )}
    app.get('/getrequest2', jsonParser, async (request, response) => {
    //my code
     )}

.....so on
    
    
        const port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`helloworld: listening on port ${port}`);
        });
```

But I am unable to access these services getting this error: Cannot GET /feedservice , when I can change ingress to this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-feedservice
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: myapp.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: feedservice
                port:
                  number: 8081
```

and

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-walletservice
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: myapp.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: walletservice
                port:
                  number: 8081
```

Only 1 service will work it says / is already used for default path, I dont want to change the host name. Also I want 1 ingress for all my 10 services. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I find the solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76733760/unable-to-access-my-services-deployed-to-amazon-eks-using-nginx-ingress-controll

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have to add this annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`  which it helps you to "Target URI where the traffic must be redirected". [Source](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)

So your new yaml file should look like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /    
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: myapp.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /feedservice
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: feedservice
                port:
                  number: 8081
          - path: /walletservice
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: walletservice
                port:
                  number: 8081
```

And also it's better to have multiple services on different port number, it's more suitable for redirection.

Comment: I have tried this , still getting Cannot GET /feedservice and Cannot GET /walletservice . Is there any other way in node  apart   from this: Do I need to add  /feedservice as prefix in all my get request                                app.get('/getrequest1', jsonParser, async (request, response) => {
    //my code
     )}
    app.get('/getrequest2', jsonParser, async (request, response) => {
    //my code
     )}

.....so on
        const port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`helloworld: listening on port ${port}`);
        });